# Собрать архив в памяти

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Всем привет.
Возник вопрос по сборке ini файла и архива.
Сейчас у меня собирается ini файл конфигурации, ложится в папку с программой и пакуется в архив на серверной машине.
Серверная машина на винде.

Возник вопрос.
Как можно работать с файлами не сохраняя их на диск ?
Планируется установка на серверную машину с линуксом. Хочется избавиться от привязки к папкам.

Сейчас сборка архива выглидит вот так

```
        var folderDir = "C:/arh";
        var resultPath = @".\result.zip";

        var ini = new IniFile("C:/arh/test.ini");
        ini.Write("accountId", "1", "Settings");
        ...

        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(folderDir, resultPath, CompressionLevel.Optimal, true);
        
        //return File(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(resultPath), "application/zip", "file.zip");
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(resultPath);
            FileContentResult result = File(bytes, "application/zip", "file.zip");
            System.IO.File.Delete(resultPath);
            return result;
        }
```

Вернее как...
На линуксе будет где-то только лежать папка с файлами для сборки.
Но собрать ini и архив, который после будет передан на фронт нужно в памяти. Вопрос... как ?

Comment: Забудьте про ZipFile и используйте ZipArchive вокруг MemoryStream.

Answer (score 3):

Псевдокод для примера:

```
using (var archiveMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(archiveMemoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        var zipItem = archive.CreateEntry(fileName);

        using (var originalFileMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes))
        {
            using (var entryStream = zipItem.Open())
            {
                originalFileMemoryStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
            }
        }
    }

    return ($"{archiveName}{FileExtensionConstants.Zip}", archiveMemoryStream.ToArray());
}
```